# gmail still shows html tags with php mail();

Tags: php, html, email, sendmail

I looked up on this website and on the php.net website which tags I should send with my php mail() function to correctly send html mail. Somehow my gmail still shows the html tags. What am I doing wrong on this?

```
$to = "$email";
        $subject = "order placed";
        $from = "noreply@snorgytees.tk";
        $message = "

        Hi, '{$_SESSION['naam']}';
        <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
        <table>
                <tr>

                <td>$Artikelnaam></td>
                <td>$maat</td>
                <td>$hoeveelheid</td>
                <td>$$echteprijs</td>
                <td>Total: $$totaalprijs;
            <br><br>Total including VAT: $$prijs_btw</td>
                </tr>

        </table>
        </body>
        </html>
        ";  
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'To: $_POST["email"]' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: noreply@snorgytees.tk' . "\r\n";
        mail($to, $subject, $from, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Foremost the text before `<html>` makes it invalid. Use view source to see what Gmail received. And then stop using the `mail()` function. Use PHPMailer/SwiftMailer. That'll also force you to fix the unparsed $_POST email address.

Comment: You also need to remove `$headers .= 'To: $_POST["email"]' . "\r\n";` since the first parameter in `mail()` is "To:"

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML rendering in Outlook 2010 and Gmail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369929/html-rendering-in-outlook-2010-and-gmail)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue about a week ago, this one helped me solve it out.
[gmail does not render html in email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21897180/gmail-does-not-render-html-in-email)

Comment: Ah, you mean the question where I posted an accepted answer ;-) I remember that one; big one that was. I'm glad it helped you also ;-)